# From megabytes /GB to bytes in node

Tags: node.js

I see always a solution for converting bytes to MB or GB

is there a proper solution to convert MB to bytes

for now, I am using as follows:

```
 MB * Math.pow(1024, 2);
```

but if I would like to convert 10GB,
then I set 10 GB = 10000 MB  and the result in bytes is different

thanks

Comment: That's because 10 GB is approximately equal (≈) 10000 MB and not exactly that much?

Comment: Start by reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte

Answer (score 6):

1 KiB = 1024 Bytes

1 MeB = 1024 KiB = 1024<sup>2</sup> Bytes

1 GiB = 1024 MeB = 1024<sup>2</sup> KiB = 1024<sup>3</sup> Bytes

More precisely

1 KiB = 2<sup>10</sup> Bytes

1 MeB = 2<sup>10</sup> KiB = 2<sup>20</sup> Bytes

1 GiB = 2<sup>10</sup> MeB = 2<sup>20</sup> KiB = 2<sup>30</sup> Bytes

Hope it helps.

`SizeInBytes = SizeInGiB * Math.pow(1024, 3);`

`SizeInBytes = SizeInMeB * Math.pow(1024, 2);`

Comment: Except that you describe the unit 1GiB (gibbyte) = 1,073,741,824 byte and not 1GB (gigabyte) = 1,000,000,000 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that you calculate the value in GiB and compare with GB.
Unfortunately the usual abbreviation GB is often used to mean GiB.
1GiB (gibbyte) = 1,073,741,824 byte and 1GB (gigabyte) = 1,000,000,000 bytes.